# Stop UIButton resizing on background image change

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, resize, setbackground

I have built a storyboard with a label, 6 UIButtons in a 3 x 2 grid and another single button below the grid.  I've put these into stack views and set up constraints which all seems to work.

I've set the background image of each button which is initially just a grey background (will be more of an icon later) and when a user clicks on the button I change the background image to be a green tick.

However, when it renders, the button increases in size so my 3 x 2 grid looks shoddy.

How can I stop the button resizing when I programmatically change the background (using `setBackgroundImage` function)?

Comment: For better understanding , can you please upload screenshot of scenarios and code as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving some fixed width or height, cause in a stack view it always take what it needs. Or you could make sure buttons are equal between them. Click and drag a button to another with alt key and set it to equal width.

Comment: Just tried that but unfortunately doesn't wok - the button increases in size when I use the green tick image.

Comment: Did you give it any constraints at all?

Comment: No, only within the stackview

Comment: Sorry I mean the rows of buttons are each in a stack view and the two row stacks are in a higher stack view

Comment: Try giving some fixed width or height, cause in a stack view it always take what it needs. Or you could make sure buttons are equal between them. Click and drag a putton to another with alt key and set it to equal width.

Comment: Great, thanks.  I've made all equal height and width which has improved the look.  I now need to work out how to keep the height and width fixed.